# Batch File Rename with Python

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

Below is my code to batch rename pictures inside a given directory

```
def multi_filename_change():
i = 0
files = askstring('Select your folder', 'Paste your directory path where your images are stored.')
for file in os.listdir(files):
    if not file.startswith('.'):
        file_name = askstring('Add file name', 'Please enter a name for your files.')
        src = file
        dst = file_name + str(i) + ".jpg"
        os.rename(src, dst)
        i += 1
```

When this is run I get the below error message:

```
os.rename(src, dst) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '360007_space-wallpaper-4k.jpg' -> 'test0.jpg'
```

I cannot seem to solve this and its probably an easy one for you experts :)

Thanks

Comment: The `file` in `file in os.listdir(files)` does not include the path name `files`. You could have seen that if you printed out `file`.

Comment: How do you include the path to file?

Comment: `files` is the path which you traverse and rename your images, so you could change `src = file` to `src = files + file`. Same goes for `dst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source should be appended with existing directory, not just filename

src =files+file

Or
src=os.path.join(files, file)

Comment: This worked perfect, only issue I have now is that the renamed images go to my python script directory and they are moved from the directory they originally where?!

Comment: That is is because we didnt update dst also, it is writing to current working directory, change dst=files+ file_name + str(i) + ".jpg".

Comment: I changed dst to: dst = files + "/" + file_name + str(i) + ".jpg" and now it works, thanks for your help!